# Change number format in renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

How do I define number format for datatable in Shiny? I would like to display 2 decimal digits only for some columns, but do not understand where it should be defined in my application. In `server.R` or `ui.R`? In `server.R`, this what I have in `renderDataTable`:

```
  output$woeTable <- renderDataTable({
    input$tryTree
    input$threshold
    # The following returns data frame with numeric columns
    get(input$dfDescr)[['variables']][[input$columns]][['woe']]
    },
    options=list(
      paging = FALSE,
      searching = FALSE)
  )
```

How do I format 2nd and 3rd column to display only two decimal digits?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31028061/2643104 using datatable() %>% formatRound()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use round command:

```
  output$woeTable <- renderDataTable({
    input$tryTree
    input$threshold
    # The following returns data frame with numeric columns
    A = get(input$dfDescr)[['variables']][[input$columns]][['woe']]
    A[,2] = round(x = A[,2],digits = 2)
    A[,3] = round(x = A[,3],digits = 2)
    A
    },
    options=list(
      paging = FALSE,
      searching = FALSE)
  )
```

you can also use `fnRowCallback` option in `renderDataTable` function if you insist to keep data with more digit and just change representation in output:

```
 output$woeTable <- renderDataTable({
    input$tryTree
    input$threshold
    # The following returns data frame with numeric columns
    get(input$dfDescr)[['variables']][[input$columns]][['woe']]
    },
    options=list(
      paging = FALSE,
      searching = FALSE,
      fnRowCallback = I("function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {ind = 2; $('td:eq('+ind+')', nRow).html( (aData[ind]).toFixed(2) );}"))
  )
```

**update for DT 1.1:**

you should change

```
fnRowCallback = I("function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {ind = 2; $('td:eq('+ind+')', nRow).html( (aData[ind]).toFixed(2) );}"))
```

to

```
rowCallback = I("function( nRow, aData) {ind = 2; $('td:eq('+ind+')', nRow).html( parseFloat(aData[ind]).toFixed(2) );}"))
```

Comment: please can you update your second version to use the new DT 1.10 function rowCallback as this is no longer working for me.

Comment: Please follow the upgrade guide https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert to change your DataTables parameter names.
It seems you need to change `fnRowCallback` to `rowCallback`. I don't have working example to change and test.

Comment: I tried that from the guide, also getting rid of the `iDisplay...` arguments and changing nRow to row and aData to data. Unfortunately still didn't work for me :-(

Comment: change the call back function according my update. you should include `parseFloat` function in java script callback. apparently data is passed as text not numbers in new version.

Comment: Thanks that works fine when you remember to change ind after you add extra columns....oops

Comment: For the latest version the code again needs an update. Here is what worked for me: `rowCallback = JS("function(nRow, aData) { ind = 2; $('td:eq('+ind+')', nRow).html(parseFloat(aData[colIndex]).toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 })); }")`